# Best constants for Gagliardo–Nirenberg inequality in the case: p=q=2

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Given a function $u$ with compact support and a bounded area $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n \geq 3$. We have the well know Gagliardo–Nirenberg inequality
$$
\|u\|_{L^2} \leq C \|Du\|_{L^2}.
$$
What is the best (known) constant $C\in\mathbb{R}$, such that this inequality holds?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality#The_Poincar%C3%A9_constant